# Fetching AccessToken returns "400 - Bad Request" for authenticating cloud service with WNS

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have been using the code  given by [MSDN article (Code given by step 6)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868252%28v=win.10%29.aspx). The problem is that it uses
    HttpUtility
    WebClient 
classes which are not available in windows metro style framework and therefire i modified GetAccessToken(....) method as follows.

```
protected OAuthToken GetAccessToken(string secret, string sid)
{
var urlEncodedSecret = WebUtility.UrlEncode(secret);
var urlEncodedSid = WebUtility.UrlEncode(sid);

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client_id", urlEncodedSid);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client_secret", urlEncodedSecret);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("scope", "notify.windows.com");

Task<string> responseResult = null;

try
{
Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.GetAsync("https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf");

responseResult = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
// Display the error message
}

return GetOAuthTokenFromJson(responseResult.Result);
}
```

the problem is that it returns "400 "Bad Request" as the result. When checked from Google it suggests that i have not set headers correctly.
As [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465435.aspx#send_notification_request) says i have set all required headers as follows to fetch the access token which in turn will be used to send a notification

Wish someone would help me out to figure out this. Thanx :)

Comment: Can anybody please help me out here...

Comment: You do not need to use .net 4.5 framework because this code is supposed to run in the server side (your own cloud) and hence use ASP and you can do it the same way MSDN suggested. But the issue still remains.

Hope somebody will help out.....