# AccessToken for Windows Push Notifications returns Bad Request 400

Tags: asp.net, push-notification, windows-store-apps

**PLEASE HELP!! Can't figure out why this simple code given by MSDN doesn't work....**

I am using the following code in GetAccessToken() as given in the [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868252%28v=win.10%29.aspx) to get the access token to be used in windows notifications, but it returns "Bad Request 400"

PACKAGE_SECURITY_IDENTIFIER, CLIENT_SECRET are the values obtained when the app was registered with the Windows Store Dashboard

```
string urlEncodedSid = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(PACKAGE_SECURITY_IDENTIFIER);
string urlEncodedSecret = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(CLIENT_SECRET);

string body = String.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=notify.windows.com", urlEncodedSid, urlEncodedSecret);

string response;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    response = client.UploadString("https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf", body);
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.......

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetching AccessToken returns "400 - Bad Request" for authenticating cloud service with WNS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105405/fetching-accesstoken-returns-400-bad-request-for-authenticating-cloud-servic)

Comment: @ConradFrix - hmm I voted to close the question that you linked. We shouldn't close them both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason for the error response. In fact it is the wrong PACKAGE_SECURITY_IDENTIFIER and CLIENT_SECRET.

DO NOT type the values. Because associated ASCII values differ. Therefore it is always better to copy and paste directly.

You will probably will get the access token with the simple code snippet.

Cheers

Comment: I had the same problem, however it find the return value of `400 Bad Request` a bit misleading as it suggests some syntax error in the request and not an authentication problem.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem has to do with either an incorrect package identifier, and / or incorrect client secret.

From the MSDN page [Push notification service request and response headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868245.aspx):

```
RESPONSE          DESCRIPTION
---------------   --------------------------
200 OK            The request was successful.
400 Bad Request   The authentication failed.
```

**Update** - I ran the code from the question, using FAKE credentials.

Here is the RAW HTTP request:

```
POST https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: login.live.com
Content-Length: 88
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=test&client_secret=test&scope=notify.windows.com
```

Here is the server's RAW response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Length: 66
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-WLID-Error: 0x80045A78
PPServer: PPV: 30 H: BAYIDSLGN2A055 V: 0
Date: Thu, 21 Mar 2013 12:34:19 GMT
Connection: close

{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid client id"}
```

You will note that the response is a **400**. There is also some json that indicates the type of error. In *my case*, the error is `Invalid client id`. You probably want to take a look at your response - it will give you an indication of what happened.

I used [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to debug the request/ response.

Comment: 400 Bad Request......... This indicates that there is SOMETHING WRONG WITH PROTOCOL! The request is being turned down by the server.
I suspect if either PACKAGE_SECURITY_IDENTIFIER or CLIENT_SECRET is wrong then it should return some other error code; something like 500.
Error code 400 means request is sent but it is turned down by the server. Isn't it?

Comment: Were u able to get the access token after changing PACKAGE_SECURITY_IDENTIFIER or CLIENT_SECRET?

Comment: @Kasun - I haven't personally tried to get the access token. Regarding the 400 - please look at the link I provided. It says that for THIS request a 400 means authentication failure.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the new HttpClient API and you're sure you've copied and pasted the SID/secret values correct, you might be experiencing this issue because of encoding, provided you're using the `FormUrlEncodedContent` class as the content of your POST operation.

Contrary to the examples in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868206.aspx), you don't want to URL encode the SID and secret values before adding them to the KeyValuePair collection. This is because encoding is implied by the `FormUrlEncodedContent` class, though I'm not seeing any [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent(v=vs.118).aspx) for this behavior. Hopefully this saves someone some time because I've been wrestling with this all night...