# Upload files to Google Drive in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, google-drive-api

**UPDATE 1**

I think I am using incorrect URL, [this doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/folder) says to use "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files" & [this doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#multipart) says to use "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart". Though I am getting same 400 bad request.

Can I use Google Drive upload REST API in background uploader class?

---

I am following [this doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#multipart) from Google Drive to upload files but I am getting 400 - Bad request. What's wrong with my code?

```
public static async Task UploadFileAsync(Token AuthToken, StorageFile file, DriveFile objFolder)
{
    try
    {
        if (!httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Authorization"))
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", AuthToken.TokenType + " " + AuthToken.AccessToken);
        }

        var JsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objFolder);
        /*JsonMessage = {"title":"c4611_sample_explain.pdf","mimeType":"application/pdf","parents":[{"id":"root","kind":"drive#fileLink"}]}*/
        var JsonReqMsg = new StringContent(JsonMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var fileBytes = await file.ToBytesAsync();

        var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes));
        form.Add(JsonReqMsg);

        form.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/related");

        var UploadReq = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart"), form);

        if (UploadReq.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var UploadRes = await UploadReq.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess - a lot of times, a "400 bad request" means something is wrong with the authentication (invalid username/ password/ other). One example here: [AccessToken for Windows Push Notifications returns Bad Request 400](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517822/accesstoken-for-windows-push-notifications-returns-bad-request-400).

Comment: My guess is, the problem coudl be related because you are using `MultipartFormDataContent` instead of `MultipartContent` and the `Content-Type: multipart/related` may be overwritten. Fiddler traces would help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You must use https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files

I have a working sample here (sorry, the JSON string is hard coded):

```
// Multipart file upload
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string uriString = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?key=<your-key>&access_token=<access-token>&uploadType=multipart";
Uri uri = new Uri(uriString);

HttpContent metadataPart = new StringContent(
    "{ \"title\" : \"My File\"}",
    Encoding.UTF8, 
    "application/json");

HttpContent mediaPart = new StringContent(
    "The naughty bunny ate all the cookies.",
    Encoding.UTF8,
    "text/plain");

MultipartContent multipartContent = new MultipartContent();
multipartContent.Add(metadataPart);
multipartContent.Add(mediaPart);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, multipartContent);
string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```